# Unexpected result from Python re.search for command line output

Tags: python, regex, windows, search, ffmpeg

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to run an ffmpeg command (in Windows) and then extract the part of the output that has the frame count with a regex expression using `re.search`. Sometimes, not always, I get the wrong result from search even if the printed command output string clearly shows what I expect.

When I use `re.findall` I get 2 results, the "wrong" one and the expected one, but in the output string of the command I still only see one option. I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
import re
import subprocess

# path to video with 300 frames
cmd = r'ffmpeg -i C:\...\300frames_HUD.avi -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output_info = p.communicate()[0]

regex = r'(frame=\s*)([0-9]+)'
search_result = re.search(regex, output_info)
findall_result = re.findall(regex, output_info)
print "SEARCH"
print '0', search_result.group(0)
print '1', search_result.group(1)
print '2', search_result.group(2)

print "FIND ALL"
print findall_result
```

Here are the results I get:

```
SEARCH
0 frame=  293
1 frame=  
2 293
FIND ALL
[('frame=  ', '293'), ('frame=  ', '300')]
```

And here is the printed `output_info`, the ffmpeg command output I'm searching on:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-15-c467328 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\...\300frames_HUD.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 373255 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 960x540, 374496 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : V
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 960x540, q=2-31, 374496 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : V
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  300 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=19.4x    
video:455625kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I'm essentially looking for the 300 number in `frame=  300`.
I can reproduce this easily when I execute it inside my IDE (pycharm) twice in a row quickly.

Comment: sorry it seems you get more than one `frame=num` option. And `re.search` simply returns the first found. So the problem is not in regex but in why you get 2 such options printed in the first place

Comment: @NikosM. I'm thinking the same, the strange part is that when I print it only outputs the last in the console, maybe the command outputs twice but python somehow only passes the last one to my print statement.

Comment: @NikosM. I figured it out, posted the explanation in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's not a regex issue, I'm actually getting more than 1 result from the command output but there is a carriage return ('\r') so only the last one was showing.

I can see it by escaping special characters:

```
import subprocess
# path to video with 300 frames
cmd = r'ffmpeg -i C:\...\300frames_HUD.avi -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output_info = str(p.communicate()[0]).encode('string-escape')
print output_info
```

The result essentially looks like this:

```
"\r\nframe=  239 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=N/A speed=15.9x    \rframe=  300 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A speed=16.5x"
```

In short, this is a bit of a quirk with the ffmpeg command and using `re.findall` to get the very last result seems like the right solution.

Comment: maybe the first frames are the original and the next are the output  result frames, if some processing took place (just guessing)